# Liquibase createTable not creating primary Key

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-cli

I am using MySQL, using Liquibase (Liquibase Version: 4.23.1), I am generating a table in the changeset and in another changeset, I am using precondition to check if the primary key exists and then only insert the record.

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-latest.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-latest.xsd">
    <changeSet author="adam" id="1693111591793-1">
        <createTable catalogName="studentdb" tableName="student">
            <column autoIncrement="true" name="student_id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints nullable="false" primaryKeyName="pk_student_id" primaryKey="true" />
            </column>
            <column name="student_name" type="VARCHAR(20)" />
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="adam" id="1693111591793-2">
        <preConditions>
            <primaryKeyExists tableName="student" primaryKeyName="pk_student_id" />
        </preConditions>
        <insert catalogName="studentdb" tableName="student">
            <column name="student_id" valueNumeric="1" />
            <column name="student_name" value="Mac" />
        </insert>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
enter code here
```

the command is `liquibase update`

The id column has constraints

```
<constraints nullable="false" primaryKeyName="pk_student_id" primaryKey="true" />
```

but still the precondition

```
<preConditions>
                <primaryKeyExists tableName="student" primaryKeyName="pk_student_id" />
            </preConditions>
```

throwing error as below

```
    Migration failed for changeset changelog.mysql.xml::1693111591793-2::adam:
     Reason:
          changelog.mysql.xml : Primary Key does not exist on the student
  - Caused by: Preconditions Failed
```

what am i missing?